# gulp-sass with Gulp 4.0 and gulp-cli 4.0 not piping css

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am working with the latest version of Node, Gulp and gulp-cli. My gulpfile.js is exactly like this. Trying out gulp to teach myself.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('default', function(){
    return gulp.src("./styles/_site.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./public"));
});
```

When I run gulp, I get nothing at the destination. No error is thrown.

I removed the pipe to sass plugin and ran the task, which then is expected to simply copy the file to the destination), and it did.

Then I used gulp-plumber on the stream.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber');


gulp.task('default', function(){
    try {

        var bla = sass();

        var blah =  gulp.src("./styles/_site.scss")
            .pipe(plumber({
                handleError: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.emit('end');
                }
            }))
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./public"));
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        var blah =  gulp.src("./styles/_site.scss")
                        .pipe(gulp.dest("./public"));
    } finally {
        return blah;
    }
});
```

I use vs code (again, the latest version;) to debug..

[image: This I debugged to look at sass()]

The task ran with no errors caught, even with the plumber. I am lost here and would really appreciate some suggestions.

PS: I tried out gulp-less to see if it could convert from *.less to *.css and it did. Had no issues there.

Comment: btw, try catch won't work as you expected, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `_site.scss` to `site.scss`.

`gulp-sass` [quietly skips all files starting with an underscore](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/v2.3.2/index.js#L28). This is because as a convention, partials (i.e. files that you want to import but should not compile to a separate CSS output) [must have their name starting with an underscore](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).

Since you intend to output a CSS file for this input SCSS file, you should **not** have it marked as a partial, thus you should not have a leading underscore.

Comment: Thanks m8! Really :P

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad I can imagine your frustration you had with this issue. :P Glad I could help!